# Django Vite Vue 3 Dynamic import Issue

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

Why is the below import not working in Vue 3?

```
import Home from `./${store.data}/Home.vue`;
```

The ***console.log(`${store.data}`***) outputs the name of the folder correctly which is *folder_1* for now.

The below import works perfectly well though:

```
import Home from './folder_1/Home.vue';
```

I have tried string concatenation with + symbol also but that also does not work. This .vue file is loaded from App.vue via `<router-view></router-view>`.

Please guide how to make the import work?

Update:
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "`./${store.data}/Home.vue`"
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`

Update:
Tried defineAsyncComponent which works in a Vite application when using only Vue + Vite. However I am facing issue when using through Django. The following is the dev build code of package.json:

```
"dev": "vite build --mode development --base /static/vue-dev --outDir ./src/staticfiles/vue-dev -w",
```

I have added "type": "module" also for checking in package.json.

The error faced now is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Update:
A simple Django Vite Vue application (default Vite app) is also facing the same issue. Code share here: https://github.com/Jayesh-Mahato/djangovitevue/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`defineAsyncComponent`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#async-components) :

```html
<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
//....
const Home = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import(`./${store.data}/Home.vue`)
)
</script>

<template>
  <Home />
</template>
```

Comment: Its not working. This .vue file is loaded from App.vue using <router-view></router-view>.
All works fine i give the path manually within ' '

Comment: Do you have any working example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the router, you can use [Lazy Loading Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html).
Something like this:

```
const router = createRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: () => import(`@/${store.data}/Home.vue`)
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: No not in the router. I need to do it inside of another component that is loaded by router-view.

Comment: Then use `defineAsyncComponent` as Boussadjra Brahim said above. Or reproduce the code somewhere to see the error.

Comment: I have added the code link.

Comment: I don't see in the given example where you apply `${store.data}`!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using `defineAsyncComponent` so I used https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import instead. I also used this answer as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300702. Here is a complex example from my project:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { shallowRef, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const { locale } = useI18n();
const localeComponent = shallowRef();

watchEffect(async () => {
    const module = await import(`./Comp.${locale.value}.md`);
    localeComponent.value = module.default;
});
</script>

<template>
    <component :is="localeComponent"></component>
</template>
```

`locale` is a ref, so when it's set somewhere else component is loaded dynamically. Also it's a markdown component and it's transformed using a plugin, but .vue files work the same. Finally this single file component is rendered inside `<router-view></router-view>`

This is also working after `vite build --base /your/path`

I hope this gives you or other people facing similar issues a path to work on.

Comment: This is written in your provided Vue link: Note that variables only represent file names one level deep. If file is 'foo/bar', the import would fail. For more advanced usage, you can use the glob import feature......

But my dynamic imports are more than 1 level deep at various other places.

Comment: Actually loading from 'foo/bar' works, but it doesn't work if the variable contains that path. So you need more tricks to turn that variable into multiple variables and load like this `./${levelOne}/${levelTwo}.vue`. By the way don't waste time on glob, because the same link says: You should also be aware that all the arguments in the import.meta.glob must be passed as literals. You can NOT use variables or expressions in them.